# single static member function has static variable, will have multiple instatnce

Tags: c++, c++17

I have seen in stackoverflow that

```
    //define in .h
    inline void fun()
    {
        static int i; // one instance include in multiple cpp
    }
    static inline void fun1()
    {
        static int i; // multiple instance included in multiple cpp
    }
```

I often write signleton in such a pattern

```
   //define in .h
   class Singleton
   {
     static Singleton& Instance()
     {
          static Singleton s;
          return s;
     }
   private:
     int i;
   }
```

a lot of coders write in this way, Can someone explain is it correct, how C++ ensure one instance?
actually in the inline and static inline version, there is no clear cpp declaration to ensure single instance.

Comment: The standard (over-simplistically) only requires that calling of a function runs consistently whether the function is inline or not, and that an implementation correct any concerns to meet the one-definition rule.  How this is achieved varies between implementations (compiler, etc) - the `i` in `fun1()` is `static` so the implementation must ensure that all calls of `fun1()` use the same `i`.  Some implementations (compilers) use reference counting - when `fun1()` is called and the count is zero, `i` is initialised and the count incremented.  But implementations are not *required* to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard does not "ensure" anything.

The C++ standard specifies the observed results, what happens as the result of this declaration

It is up to each C++ compiler to implement this C++ specification in the manner that produces the specified results.

The C++ standard does not specify exactly how the compiler and the linker go about doing this. The low level details that produces these results are not specified or mandated by the C++ standard, in any way. This is entirely up to the compiler and the linker.

Having said that: the common approach is for the compiler to produce an instance of the static object in every compiled `.cpp` file. It is also tagged in some manner that uniquely identifies it; and indicates that, when linked with other translation units, only one instance of the uniquely-identified object (in all the compiled object files) is produced in the final linked executable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that was inherited from C and you have to go back quite a bit in history. So a long time a ago in a language not quite C++ ...

The `inline` keyword was just a hint to the compiler that you would like that function to get inlined. Now some compilers just ignored it because nothing said you had to inline functions marked `inline`. Some compilers addded a fudge factor to their automatic inline heuristic to make it more likely to get inlined. Others always inlined.

This then caused a problems for functions defined in headers because when the function was not actually inlined you ended up with the same function in multiple compilation units and then the linker complained.

Some compilers marked `inline` functions so that the linker would ignore duplicate definitions. But to be portable you had to mark your functions `static inline`. That way, even if the function is present in each compilation unit, the function isn't exported and doesn't collide with definitions of the same function in other compilation units. Drawback is that you get multiple copies of the same function, which is a problem when you have local static variables or use the address of the function.

Warp forward to the near present...

Compilers have gotten a lot smarter about inlining automatically and the feature to mark `inline` function to allow multiple defintions has kind of taken hold and that is the meaning of the `inline` specifier in C++. Since C++17 this also holds for inline variables, not just functions.

So `inline` causes the compiler to mark the function (or variable) in the object file for the linker to

1. Allow multiple definitions without error or warning.
2. Pick any one of the definitions and replace all the other instances with that one.

All duplicates of the inline function will end up with the same address and any local static variable will end up with a single instance too. All copies become the same object.

PS: using a static local variable for a singleton is imho the best way as it avoids the *Static Initialization Order Fiasco* as much as can be and is thread safe.